# How to select image size for paperclip when using act_as_api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, paperclip

I'm using the Paperclip gem and [act_as_api](https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api) gem to configure my API. 
I have a attribute called image in Product model

When using act_as_api with the following definition:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...
  acts_as_api

  api_accessible :public do |t|
    t.add :id
    t.add :name
    t.add :price
    t.add :image
  end

 ....
```

How can I decide how to set the image size like (:medium, :thumb etc) which paperclip provides in the api template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a lambda to the `add` call like this:

`t.add lambda{|product| product.image.url(:medium) }, :as => :image`

More information can be found in the wiki of the repo: 
https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api/wiki/Calling-a-lambda-in-the-api-template